How do I create a Scala Function that can be called from the bash command line?
For instance, if i wanted to create a script that adds two numbers, how would I be able to call the scala script where I have a function that takes in two arguments?

You can write a Scala program that takes arguments, is callable from shell, and produces output to stdout. But (afaik) you cannot write a Scala function that is callable directly from shell (indirectly calling the Scala program which calls the function is just the first case).

I see, thanks for the clarification. Writing a program is more what I'm thinking then. Do you know what the shell syntax would be to call the program that takes in arguments?

What is the meta-problem you are trying to solve here? Writing a small cli app?


Writing a program is more what I'm thinking then. Do you know what the shell syntax would be to call the program that takes in arguments?

Here's a rudimentary Scala script:
#!/usr/bin/env scala

if (args.size == 2) println(args(0).toInt + args(1).toInt)
else println("Needs exatcly two arguments.")

Save it, for example, as add.scala, then make it executable using chmod +x, and run it by prepending ./:
$ chmod +x add.scala
$ ./add.scala 23 45
68


I'd add that if you're using Scala 3, you can just say @main def add(a: Int, b: Int) = println(a + b).
